# Django Rest Framework Custom URL in Nested Serializer

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm triying to create a Custom URL in a nested serializer.
This is my serializer.py ->

```
class SerieSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.username')
picture = serializers.ImageField()

class Meta:
    model = Serie
    fields = ('url', 'name', 'genre', 'director', 'release', 'seasons', 'review', 'picture', 'actors', 'created_by')
```

and this is the result:

```
[
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/series/1/",
    "name": "Mr. Robot",
    "genre": "DRAMA",
    "director": "Sam Esmail",
    "release": "2015-06-24",
    "seasons": 2,
    "review": "Mr. Robot es una serie de televisión estadounidense creada por Sam Esmail. Se estrenó el 24 de junio de 2015 en la cadena USA Network. El mismo día la serie se renovó para una segunda temporada, estrenada el 13 de julio de 2016. El 16 de agosto del mismo año Mr. Robot fue renovado para una tercera temporada a estrenarse en 2017.",
    "picture": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dqohbm9y4/image/upload/v1487190362/uasfb8maqzh9urp4bvrd.png",
    "actors": [
        "http://localhost:8000/actors/3/",
        "http://localhost:8000/actors/4/"
    ],
    "created_by": "mosthated"
}
]
```

But I need something like this, in "Actors":

```
[
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/series/1/",
    "name": "Mr. Robot",
    "genre": "DRAMA",
    "director": "Sam Esmail",
    "release": "2015-06-24",
    "seasons": 2,
    "review": "Mr. Robot es una serie de televisión estadounidense creada por Sam Esmail. Se estrenó el 24 de junio de 2015 en la cadena USA Network. El mismo día la serie se renovó para una segunda temporada, estrenada el 13 de julio de 2016. El 16 de agosto del mismo año Mr. Robot fue renovado para una tercera temporada a estrenarse en 2017.",
    "picture": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dqohbm9y4/image/upload/v1487190362/uasfb8maqzh9urp4bvrd.png",
    "actors": [
        "Rami Malek": "http://localhost:8000/actors/3/",
        "Christian Slater": "http://localhost:8000/actors/4/"
    ],
    "created_by": "mosthated"
}
]
```

I need this to send the profile to call for example: go to "Rami Malek" profile with your name as URL, or display it and display the URL with your primary key.

If you can help me, thank so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a customActorSerializer like below and link it with SerieSerializer.

```
class ActorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = ('url','actor_name')

class SerieSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.username')
    picture = serializers.ImageField()
    actors = ActorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Serie
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'genre', 'director', 'release', 'seasons', 'review', 'picture', 'actors', 'created_by')
```

hope it works.